# Lebesgue non-measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Can we give an example of Lebesgue non-measurable function, for which set $\{x: f(x)=C\}~\forall C\in\mathbb{R}$ is measurable? Thanks.

Comment: You can get such a functions by adding pretty much any analytic function to a non-measurable function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let $S$ a non-measurable subset of $]0,+\infty[$. Define $$g(x)=\begin{cases} x\text{ if } x\in S\\-x\text{ if } x\notin S\end{cases}$$

$g^{-1}(y)$ is finite $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}$, but $\{ g\geq 0\}\setminus\ ]-\infty,0]=S$ is not measurable.

Comment: What does $]0, +\infty]$ denote?

Comment: @DavidZhang Editing right... NOW!

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure what $]0, +\infty[$ denotes either. Is it the complement of $[0, +\infty]$, perhaps?

Comment: I believe $]$ and $[$ are notations of open intervals. It's uncommon, but, for example, I've seen it in Brown's _Topology and Groupoids_.

Comment: @DavidZhang Oh, ok. One sometimes uses reversed square brackets to exclude the extremal point of the interval. For instance $]0,+\infty[=(0,+\infty)$.

In Italy it's not that rare, I guess.

Comment: Its much more common in continental Europe.

Comment: $g$ is a function. What does $\{g \geq 0\}$ denote?

Comment: @meisterluk A very common shorthand notation for $$\{x\in (0,\infty)\,:\, g(x)\ge 0\}$$ Or, more of the same, $g^{-1}((0,\infty))$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah, thanks.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Can we take $g(x)=\begin{cases} x\text{ if } x\in S\\-|x|\text{ if } x\notin S\end{cases}$ so that $\{g\geq 0\} = S$ instead of dealing with $\{ g\geq 0\}\setminus\ ]-\infty,0]=S,$ in which latter is, to me, more complicated.

Comment: @Idonknow Yes, I guess.

Comment: $]a,b[$ are [known](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25378/mathjax-and-the-french-notation-for-open-intervals) as the French brackets. There are many other countries in Europe (minus Britain, Ireland, Iceland) in which this notation would seem as unusual as it is in Anglosphere. I don't know if the notation due to Bourbaki, but they might've played a role.

Answer (score 13):

Take $V$ to be a non-measurable set on $[0,1]$,
 and consider on $[0,1]$ the function
$$ f(x) := x \mathbf{1}_V(x) + (-10 -x)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]\setminus V}(x) $$
where $\mathbf{1}_V$ is the indicator function of $V$,
$$ \mathbf{1}_V(x) := \begin{cases} 1 & x∈ V \\ 0 & x \notin V \end{cases} $$Then the preimage of any $C∈ℝ$ is a singleton or empty and hence measurable.

Its also not hard to use this idea to make a non-measurable function on $ℝ$, also satisfying your criterion: 
$$ f(x) := e^x \mathbf{1}_V(x) + (-10 -e^x)\mathbf{1}_{ℝ \setminus V}(x)$$

Comment: Excuse me, what does $\mathbf{1}_V(x)$ mean?

Comment: 1 if x is in V, 0 otherwise.

Comment: @olegas You'll often see it called the *indicator function* or *characteristic function* of the set $V$, though the first name is preferred since "characteristic function" has different meanings in different fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit in my question.