# A nonmeasurable function such that $|f|$ is measurable, and the preimage of every point is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Give an example of  nonmeasurable function $f:(\mathbb{R}, Leb)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $|f|$ is measurable and for  every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ , $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is a measurable set

My idea: suppose $E$ is a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$  and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in E$ and $f(x)=x-e^x$ for $x\in E^{c}$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? You're more likely to get good answers if you show you've tried the problem. What have you tried? Why did it not work?

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237593/lebesgue-non-measurable-function/1237612#1237612) incidentally satisfies "$\lvert g\rvert$ measurable" as well.

Comment: yes. suppose $E$ is a unmeasurable set and $f:R\rightarrow R$and $f(x)=x, x\in E$ and$f(x)=x-e^x , x\in E^{c}$ , E is a subset of [0,1]

Comment: @user330305 I don't see why the function you write should have measurable absolute value.

Answer (score 4):

Simplify your example by taking $f(x) =x$ for $x\in E$ and $f(x)=-x$ for $x\in E^c$.