# Why does an admissible control need to be measurable?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, epidemiology

I am reviewing some literature on controlling [SIR models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology). I have come across the following article

- Khalid Hattaf, Noura Yousfi, [Optimal control of a delayed HIV infection model with immune response using an efficient numerical method](https://doi.org/10.5402/2012/215124), ISRN Biomathematics, 2012. [[ZBL1268.92089](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1268.92089)]

where the authors wrote that their control should be measurable to be admissible, and I don't quite get why. Can somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: Can you think of a non-measurable control input?

Comment: I'm not able to link the mathematical definition of measurable functions with this. Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237593/339790)